# What is a pareto optimal strategy for two player general sum games?

Tags: game-theory

What is the definition that a strategy for player one and player two to be pareto optimal?

Answer (score 1):

An outcome of a game is pareto optimal, if there is no other outcome that makes at least one player better off and no player worse off.

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{1cm}|}
\hline \text{Player 1 / Player 2} &  \text{strategy 1}  &\text{strategy 2}   \\ \hline \hline \hline\text{strategy 1}& 10/10 &0/15\\ \hline \text{strategy 2}& 12/8&3/3  \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Thus the pareto optimal outcomes are $(10/10);(0/15);(12/8)$

Comment: I have found that through a textbook as well , but what is a strategy for players that is pareto optimal?

Comment: I don't think it has any meaning for a particular strategy to be pareto optimal. However, you could say that a particular _strategy profile_ is pareto optimal if the resulting outcome is pareto optimal.